# Web Application Using FB API from trusted IP address - Security Challenge

Tags: facebook, security

I have searched for "public IP" and read all articles shown. I have a question that I cannot answer with my search.

We have a web application running on a dozen kiosks installed at a national attraction. The FB API is called when users would like to post their personal picture (taken by our system) to FB. We do not allow the user to augment the posting in any way, only log in.

Is there any way to register a physical or IP address as "trusted" so that the continual flow of guest users at this attraction do not run into the "unknown IP address" security instance? We allow guests to post tens of thousands of photos to FB on a continual basis. This security hurdle causes 50% of users to abandon the effort to post to FB.

We have a three year history with the same hardware running at same location running through millions of visitors who want to post to FB. Fixing this security hurdle somehow would double the number of posts to FB.  Thank you.  Mike

Comment: I think you would have to contact Facebook directly to try to negotiate this.  Good luck!

Comment: I wish I could figure out how to contact them. Calling and general help emails have not worked so far. I need a consultant for this, I think.